# Why am I getting Grails SessionFactoryProxy?

Tags: hibernate, grails, sessionfactory

I have inherited an older Grails 1.2 application, and I am trying to upgrade it to the latest Grails 2.1.2. Something has changed in Grails because this code from resources.groovy used to work:

```
searchIndexBuilder(SearchIndexBuilder) {bean ->
    bean.singleton = true
    indexManager = ref("indexManager")
    sessionFactory = ref("sessionFactory")
}
```

Combined with this code from SearchIndexBuilder.java:

```
private void injectHibernateEventListener() {
    try {
        HibernateEventListener hel = initHibernateEventListener();
        SessionFactoryImpl hibernateSessionFactory = (SessionFactoryImpl) sessionFactory; //fails here
        EventListeners hibernateEventListeners = hibernateSessionFactory.getEventListeners();
etc....
```

The code fails at the cast because I get an instance of SessionFactoryProxy which does not extend SessionFactoryImpl.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is new in Grails 2.0, it's to support domain class reloading. Before 2.0 changing a domain class during run-app would cause the application to restart, but with the new reloading agent this isn't necessary. But since the persistence configuration may have changed, Grails rebuilds the `SessionFactory`. But due to the way Hibernate is configured, other classes have a reference to the old one, so it cannot be replaced without knowing every class that has a reference. So the proxy is used to contain the replaceable real instance, and everyone calls methods on the proxy. When the `SessionFactory` is replaced it's entirely internal to the proxy and other users don't know that anything happened.

This means that the `SessionFactory` won't be a `SessionFactoryImpl`, but the point of interfaces is to abstract away the concrete implementation class, so it's a bad practice to cast to what you expect the real class to be. This should work in older and current versions of Grails:

```
SessionFactory hibernateSessionFactory = (SessionFactory)sessionFactory;
```

Comment: So how do I get a reference to the EventListeners then? SessionFactory doesn't define that method. It's also not clear to me if SessionFactoryProxy does either.

Comment: Call `getCurrentSessionFactory()` which will get the current real proxied `SessionFactoryImpl`

Comment: That requires that I cast to SessionFactoryProxy. Is this going to work in production? The documentation for the class implies that it wouldn't.

Comment: Or maybe the better question is what will the bean type be in production and test? I can certainly do a type check in the code and cast appropriately although it seems less than ideal to have to do this.

Comment: This is only done in development since reloading isn't supported in other environments.

Comment: So the original code (which is suboptimal, as you pointed out) would work in production, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's just a dev mode thing.